# When are mongodb indexes updated?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

## Question

Are mongodb indexes updated before the success of a write operation is reported to the application or do index updates run in the background? If they run in the background: is there a way to wait for an index update to complete?

## Background

I have a document

```
person1obj = {
  email: 'user@domain.tld',
  [...]
}
```

in a `people` collection where a *unique* index is applied to the `email` field. Now I'd like to insert another document

```
person2obj = {
  email: 'user@domain.tld',
  [...]
}
```

Obviously, I have to change the `email` field of `person1` before `person2` can be inserted. With mongoose, the code looks like

```
mongoose.model('Person').create(person1obj, function (err, person1) {
  // person1 has been saved to the db and 'user@domain.tld' is 
  // added to the *unique* email field index

  // change email for person1 and save
  person1.email = 'otheruser@domain.tld';
  person1.save(function(err, person1) {
    // person1 has been updated in the db

    // QUESTION: is it guaranteed that 'user@domain.tld' has been removed from
    //           the index? 

    // inserting person2 could fail if the index has not yet been updated
    mongoose.model('Person').create(person2obj, function (err, person2) {
      // ...
    });
  });
});
```

I have seen a random fail of my unit tests with the error `E11000 duplicate key error index` which made me wonder if index updates run in the background.

This question probably is related to mongodb's [write concern](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/) but I couldn't find any documentation on the actual process for index updates.

Comment: Index updates happen as a part of the write operation. They do not run in the background. Now, if you're reading from secondaries, then you might get stale data, but this has nothing to do with how indexes work.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thx! do you have a pointer to docs where the behavior is explained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/indexes/) (emphasis mine):

> ### How do write operations affect indexes?
>
> Any write operation that alters an indexed field requires an update to the index in addition to the document itself. If you update a document that causes the document to grow beyond the allotted record size, then MongoDB must update all indexes that include this document **as part of the update operation**.
>
> Therefore, if your application is write-heavy, creating too many indexes might affect performance.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least in the case of unique indexes, the indexing does **not** run in the background. This is evident by the fact that when you try to write a new document with a duplicate key that is suppose to be unique you get a duplicate key error.

If indexing was to happen asynchronously in the background, Mongo would not be able to tell if the write actually succeeded. Thus the indexing must happen during the write sequence.

While I have no evidence for this (though Mongo is open source, if you have enough time you can look it up), I believe that all indexing is done during the write sequence, even if its not a unique index. It wouldn't make sense to have special logic for writes that affect a unique index.